# How to use two different data sets into two different result sets in a single report of SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

"Cannot read the next data row for the data set error converting data type nvarchar to float" while using two different datasets in a single SSRS report.
But the same works with 2 different reports.
Please help me with this.
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: It's tough to work out what the issue is without more details. I guess it would be a problem with one of the datasets specifically, rather than the fact that you're using two. Are you using `Lookup()` expressions?

Comment: No I am not using any lookup.
I was just trying to get  two reports at a single run by passing single parameter/variable.